# Implement my own Class Loader

Tags: classloader

I 'm trying to Implement my own Class Loader which is must be transparency for application, And NoClassDefError error still occurs.
here is my Custom Class Loader:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{

    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.print(name);
        if(!"MyObject".equals(name)){
            System.out.println("Super load class function");
                return super.loadClass(name);

        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Go to load class function");
            String url = "file:C:/Users/ahmad/Desktop/CustomClassLoader/class/MyObject.class";
            URL myUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int data = input.read();
            while(data != -1){
                buffer.write(data);
                data = input.read();
            }
            input.close();
            byte[] classData = buffer.toByteArray();
            return defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

here is my main code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException{      
        MyObjectInterface myobj = new MyObject();       
        System.out.println(myobj.getHelloMessage());
        }

}
```

with -Djava.system.class.loader="CustomClassLoader" parameter for VM.

is there is any thing missed.
Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use that system property. Try using the loadClass method and reflection `Object main = loader.loadClass("Main", true).newInstance();` as suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)